# Split MVC app into multiple appdomains?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appdomain

As far as I understand it, when a request is made IIS routes it to the appropriate web application at which point your app, inheriting from HttpApplication handles the request, when you register a route in Mvc under the hood it assigns an MvcRouteHandler which ultimately leads to an MvcHandler taking over and doing normal Mvc stuff, finding the controller and action, resolving the view etc.

My question is, at the point of the request, can you separate the execution into another AppDomain? So your web application will spawn as normal with its default AppDomain but all the application logic will be loaded and handled in a separate AppDomain?

I suspect the answer to this question is probably no. I just find it a bit jarring that if you want to update a dll you then need to reload the entire application or jump through hoops with some kind of plugin architecture.

What I want to do is essentially to load the entire application into a separate AppDomain which will handle all traffic as normal, but when you drop in a new dll it'll spawn a new AppDomain, reload everything and swap out the old AppDomain and swap in the new AppDomain meaning a seamless update and transition.

The only thing I've found close to this is IIS level stuff involving maintaining two apps/application pools.

Comment: "if you want to update a dll you then need to reload the entire application". Why? If you're including a new DLL, the application has to be re-compiled to ensure it works with the new version. You can't just swap it in without the compiler verifying it's happy with it - the new one could have changed method signatures, or missing methods, or anything like that. But yeah, splitting up the functionality in to multiple app domains...you've invented something which sounds very similar to Microservices here, so yes you'd need multiple separate applications / APIs to do what you want

Comment: If you drop a new version of a dll into a web application bin directory the application restarts and reloads all the dlls, you'll only know you've got missing method or bum signature at runtime when it tries to execute and throws an exception, up till then the app doesn't care. I'm just looking for a graceful way to reload a web application without disruption to the end user.

Comment: "If you drop a new version of a dll into a web application bin directory"...that's not a supported practice as far as I know. You're supposed to import the new DLL into the source code project, re-compile the project and then deploy to the server. That's how .NET applications are supposed to be updated. Unless the publish / deploy operation is very slow, downtime will be a minute or two at the most